# Error: "Attempt to use a deleted function" when moving a promise

Tags: c++, xcode, promise, move, future

I am trying to write an example with a promise/future in it. On the example in [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) they do it and it works just fine in their online compiler. When I do it on my Mac (with the sourcecode down below) it will throw me this error indicating there is no move operator. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Header file:

```
#ifndef Demonstration9_hpp
#define Demonstration9_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

inline namespace demo9
{
    class Demonstration9
    {
    private:
        bool Job1();
        void Job2();

    public:
        void Run();
    };
}

#endif /* Demonstration9_hpp */
```

Source file:

```
#include "Demonstration9.hpp"

bool job1(string test_string)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    return test_string == "test";
}

void job2()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
}

bool Demonstration9::Run()
{
    promise<bool> j1_promise;
    future<bool> j1_future = j1_promise.get_future();
    thread t1(job1, "test", move(j1_promise));
    j1_future.wait();  // wait for result
    cout << "result=" << j1_future.get() << '\n';
    t1.join();  // wait for thread completion

    // Demonstrate using promise<void> to signal state between threads.
    promise<void> j2_promise;
    future<void> j2_future = j2_promise.get_future();
    thread t2(job2, move(j2_promise));
    j2_future.wait();
    t2.join();
}
```

Build Log:

> In file included from
>   /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:9: In
>   file included from
>   /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.hpp:13:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:342:5:
>   error: attempt to use a deleted function
>       __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:352:5:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::__thread_execute >, bool
>   (*)(std::__1::basic_string), const char *,
>   std::__1::promise , 2, 3>' requested here
>       __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:368:47:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::__thread_proxy >, bool
>   (*)(std::__1::basic_string), const char *,
>   std::__1::promise > >' requested here
>       int __ec = __libcpp_thread_create(&__t_, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());
>                                                 ^ /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:26:12:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::thread::thread), char
>   const (&)[5], std::__1::promise , void>' requested here
>       thread t1(job1, "test", move(j1_promise));
>              ^ In file included from /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:9: In
>   file included from
>   /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.hpp:12: In
>   file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:470:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:169:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:56:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:640:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:1590:5:
>   note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
>       ~__nat() = delete;
>       ^ In file included from /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:9: In
>   file included from
>   /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.hpp:13:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:342:5:
>   error: attempt to use a deleted function
>       __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:352:5:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::__thread_execute >, void (*)(),
>   std::__1::promise , 2>' requested here
>       __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:368:47:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::__thread_proxy >, void (*)(),
>   std::__1::promise > >' requested here
>       int __ec = __libcpp_thread_create(&__t_, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());
>                                                 ^ /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:34:12:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::thread::thread , void>'
>   requested here
>       thread t2(job2, move(j2_promise));
>              ^ In file included from /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.cpp:9: In
>   file included from
>   /Users/maurits/Github/CPP-Demonstrations/src/Demonstration9.hpp:12: In
>   file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:470:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:169:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:56:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:640:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:1590:5:
>   note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
>       ~__nat() = delete;
>       ^ 2 errors generated.

Comment: You should post build log, `DemonstrationInterface.hpp` content and the code invoking `Run()`. And probably reduced to mcve.

Comment: I removed the interface. It is meaningless for this code. I also added the log. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Your function signatures mismatch. `job1` for examples accepts just one argument while you are trying to pass two arguments - string and promise.

Comment: It could be that the error message is a red herring. Study the function prototypes on the page you linked and compare them to yours.

Comment: Such a silly mistake to make. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
thread t1(job1, "test", move(j1_promise));
```

is trying to invoke

```
job1("test", move(j1_promise));
```

in a separate thread. But your `job1` only takes one argument.

Comment: I had not noticed that. Thank you!